# Calling a function from outside class with user input without using global

Tags: python, class, global

I am trying to avoid using global, instead I created a class. I am having trouble calling the class, instead, I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: phone.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'NUMBER_INPUT'
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
class phone:
    
        def __init__(self,NUMBER_INPUT):
            self.NUMBER_INPUT = NUMBER_INPUT
    
        def phone_number(self):
            """validate user input of phone number"""
            while True:
                self.NUMBER_INPUT = input("Please enter your phone number: ")
                if  re.fullmatch(r"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}" ,self.NUMBER_INPUT):
                    print("You phone number is: " + self.NUMBER_INPUT)
                    break
                print("Please enter a valid phone number ex. 123-456-5678")
    
    phone().phone_number()
```

Comment: The `phone()` constructor requires a `NUMBER_INPUT` argument.

Comment: Trouble is, that is entered by the user in the function I am trying to call?

Comment: Why does the `phone_number()` method ask for a new value of `NUMBER_INPUT` instead of using the one that was created in the constructor?

Comment: If the user is supposed to enter the number when you call `phone_number()`, why does the constructor require the argument?

Comment: I want to be able to use the variable NUMBER_INPUT in a different function in the code. I was told I can do this in one of two ways 1) global variable. but pylint does not like this. 2) make a class with different function. I was doing my best to make a class. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You need to decide whether to provide it when creating the object or when calling the method. Your code does both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you neither did read documentation nor watched/read any tutorial about Python classes. So I will explain it here for you.

Class is a "object project". It may have predefined methods, predefined values. It also may have a way to construct these dynamically.

Class object at first need to be instantiated and then initiated. That means that firstly you need to create an instance of a class, then to initiate default values.

Python has 2 methods for this.

`__new__()` creates a new instance of a class and returns it. It's already realised for every Python class, but there may be special cases for you to override it.

`__init__(*args, **kwargs)` initiates values of a class. You must define non-static values here or globally in class.

So, creating a class object is achieved in python by calling class like this

```
A_instance = A(*args, **kwargs)
```

That in words means `create me instance of A with these args and kwargs`

So in your code, you are using (actualy overriding) `__init__(*args, **kwargs)` with `args = (NUMBER_INPUT,)` and `kwargs = None`.

Thus you must provide NUMBER_INPUT every time you create an object of phone, like so:

```
phone1 = phone("123-456-7890")
phone2 = phone("098-765-4321")
```

Comment: I got it thanks. I was confused as I am asking the user to enter a phone number. Will this override my creation of the object class?

Comment: No, it won't. `__init__` method was initialy created to be costumized by end user

Comment: Great, thank u!

Answer (score 1):

You must provide a value for `NUMBER_INPUT` when calling `phone()` like `phone("123").phone_number()`.

But it would be better if you will use dummy value for NUMBER_INPUT in constructor like:

```
class phone:
    
        def __init__(self):
            self.NUMBER_INPUT = ""
    
        def phone_number(self):
            """validate user input of phone number"""
            while True:
                self.NUMBER_INPUT = input("Please enter your phone number: ")
                if  re.fullmatch(r"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}" ,self.NUMBER_INPUT):
                    print("You phone number is: " + self.NUMBER_INPUT)
                    break
                print("Please enter a valid phone number ex. 123-456-5678")
    
phone().phone_number()
```